# Почасовое разбиение

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте,помогите разобраться... 
Есть таблица

```
Начало смены(SHIFT_DATE)     №оборудования(EQUIP_IDENT)    Время начала статуса(START_TIMESTAMP)      Статус(STATUS_CODE)      Время окончания статуса(END_TIMESTAMP)
```

/*Статус - к примеру оборудование стоит,двигается это все отдельные статусы*/

Задача следующая нужно разбить время статусов почасово. Проблема заключается в том, что статус может начинаться в один час а заканчиваться в другой. Как сделать так чтобы часть статуса попадала в один час а вторая часть во второй?

часы я выбрал так

```
 DISTINCT DATEADD(hh,1,DATEADD(ss, -DATEPART(ss,est.START_TIMESTAMP), DATEADD(mi, -DATEPART(mi,est.START_TIMESTAMP),dbo.season_offset(est.START_TIMESTAMP,1)))) as 'DATE_TIME_HOURS'
```

Я прикрутил одну конструкцию, но она обрезает час с одной стороны(если час конца статуса > часа начала статуса - тогда рубить по концу стартового часа), но тогда **как добыть 2-ю часть от начала 2-го часа до конца статуса?**

Я понимаю что ковыряться в чужом коде с чужой базой... но описывая словами происходящее:
1.
Выбираю часы по старту статуса
Выбираю часы по концу статуса
Оборудование
Статус
Время начала статуса 
Время конца

2. Условие во внешнем case - если час старта статуса = часу конца статуса и статус = рабочий
   тогда выбираю время статуса
   если если час = часу старта и час конца статуса > часа начала статуса 
   тогда время (начала статуса до часа начала статуса (например 18 ) + 00:59:59)

получится к примеру статус начался в 18:30:23 и закончился в 19:15:00 тогда его обрежет с 18:30:23 до 18:59:59

**Как достать часть от 19:00:00 до 19:15:00??**

```
    select
DATE_TIME_HOURS,
EQUIP_IDENT,
START_TIMESTAMP,
END_TIMESTAMP,
CASE 
        WHEN DATE_TIME_HOURS_START = DATE_TIME_HOURS_END AND tab.STATUS_CODE = 'KIO_WORK' 
        THEN DATEDIFF(SS,START_TIMESTAMP,END_TIMESTAMP)
        WHEN DATE_TIME_HOURS_START = DATE_TIME_HOURS AND DATE_TIME_HOURS_END > DATE_TIME_HOURS_START  AND  tab.STATUS_CODE = 'KIO_WORK' 
        THEN DATEDIFF(SS,START_TIMESTAMP, DATEADD(HH,-1,DATE_TIME_HOURS_START) + '00:59:59') 
        ELSE 0 END AS WORK   

from(
select 
     DISTINCT DATEADD(hh,1,DATEADD(ss, -DATEPART(ss,est.START_TIMESTAMP), DATEADD(mi, -DATEPART(mi,est.START_TIMESTAMP),dbo.season_offset(est.START_TIMESTAMP,1)))) as 'DATE_TIME_HOURS', -- Это часы
     DATEADD(hh,1,DATEADD(ss, -DATEPART(ss,est.START_TIMESTAMP), DATEADD(mi, -DATEPART(mi,est.START_TIMESTAMP),dbo.season_offset(est.START_TIMESTAMP,1)))) as 'DATE_TIME_HOURS_START', --Это час старта статуса
     DATEADD(hh,1,DATEADD(ss, -DATEPART(ss,est.END_TIMESTAMP), DATEADD(mi, -DATEPART(mi,est.END_TIMESTAMP),dbo.season_offset(est.END_TIMESTAMP,1)))) as 'DATE_TIME_HOURS_END', -- Это час конца статуса
     est.EQUIP_IDENT,
     --DATEDIFF(SS,START_TIMESTAMP,END_TIMESTAMP)as duration,
     est.STATUS_CODE,
     START_TIMESTAMP,
     END_TIMESTAMP  


from EQUIPMENT_STATUS_TRANS est

where SHIFT_DATE between @start_date and @end_date
and SHIFT_IDENT = @shift_ident
--AND DATEPART(HH,START_TIMESTAMP)=DATEPART(HH,END_TIMESTAMP)
) tab
order by EQUIP_IDENT,DATE_TIME_HOURS,START_TIMESTAMP
```

Пример выполненного запроса:

```
DATE_TIME_HOURS     EQUIP_IDENT  START_TIMESTAMP             END_TIMESTAMP      DURATION
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:00:00.000 2016-03-23 20:05:17.000 0
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:05:17.000 2016-03-23 20:06:24.000 67
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:06:24.000 2016-03-23 20:09:45.000 0
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:09:45.000 2016-03-23 20:10:05.000 20
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:10:05.000 2016-03-23 20:11:16.000 71
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:11:16.000 2016-03-23 20:14:57.000 221
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:14:57.000 2016-03-23 20:16:18.000 0
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:16:18.000 2016-03-23 20:19:57.000 219
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:19:57.000 2016-03-23 20:21:16.000 79
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:21:16.000 2016-03-23 20:24:42.000 206
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:24:42.000 2016-03-23 20:26:25.000 0
2016-03-23 21:00:00.000 11  2016-03-23 20:26:25.000 2016-03-23 20:30:29.000 244
```

Comment: А если время статуса длится более 2х часов - вам все еще нужен первый час и все остальные. Или тут уже 3 и более частей ?

Comment: Если больше тогда нужно разбить на то количество часов сколько он длиться например с 15:00 до 17:30 значит 15-16, 16-17, 17 - 17:30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаем дополнительную таблицу с целыми числами идущими подряд от 0 до максимальной продолжительности работы оборудования в часах (лучше с запасом):

```
create table seqnum(
 N int not null,
 CONSTRAINT PK_seqnum PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N)
);
insert into seqnum values(0),(1),(2),(3);
insert into seqnum select N+4 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select N+8 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select N+16 from seqnum; -- Максимальное значение 31
```

Запрос получения почасовых интервалов выглядит так:

```
select iif(S.N=0,start_timestamp,dateadd(hour,S.N,start_hour)) start_dt,
       iif(dateadd(hour,S.N+1,start_hour)>=end_timestamp,end_timestamp,
           dateadd(hour,S.N,start_hour)+'00:59:59') end_dt
  from
 (
  select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, start_timestamp), 0) start_hour,
         start_timestamp,end_timestamp,
         datediff(hour,start_timestamp,end_timestamp) period_length
    from EQUIPMENT_STATUS_TRANS
 ) E, seqnum S -- Перемножаем на порядковые номера
 where S.N<=period_length -- И отсекаем все превышающие часы
```

Обратите внимание, обрезание времени до часа происходит так `dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, start_timestamp), 0)`.

Comment: сделал немного иначе но спасибо за совет!